# how to remove Duplicate values in list of list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

```
 list_values=[("10",1),("10",2),("16",2),("16",1),("15",1)]
```

I want the result as :

```
 Result=[("10",1),("16",2),("15",1)]
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, `("16",1)` is not duplicated in the input set, so it should be in the result set.

Comment: Well, your `list_values` is a list of tuples

Comment: According to which criterion do you decide to remove ("10",2) and ("16",1) ?

Comment: Query: why you want ("16",2) why not ("16",1) and same goes for ("10",1),("10",2).?

Comment: probably by first occurrence. Use a marker set or create a dict by iterating backwards.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre just what I thought.

Comment: `list(dict(reversed(list_values)).items())`

Comment: @BearBrown surely you mean `list(reversed(list(dict(reversed(list_values)).items())))` :)

Comment: nope: `list(dict(reversed(list_values)).items())` works just fine

Comment: may be `list(dict(reversed(list_values)).items())[::-1]`

Comment: dictionary will trash the order anyway. So it depends if OP wants to preserve original order or not

Comment: @ferrix You are right and still OP gets upvoted!

Answer (score 3):

Looks very much like [How do you remove duplicates from a list whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-whilst-preserving-order), but just "carrying" the second element, not including it in the hash/comparison/whatever.

Two ways of doing this:

Either use a marker set to note down the occurrences of the first values:

```
list_values=[("10",1),("10",2),("16",2),("16",1),("15",1)]

seen = set()

seen_add = seen.add

result = []
for k,v in list_values:
    if k not in seen:
        seen_add(k)
        result.append([k,v])

print(result)
```

yields (preserves order):

```
[['10', 1], ['16', 2], ['15', 1]]
```

or use a dictionary on reversed items to keep the first value only:

```
result = list(dict(reversed(list_values)).items())

print(result)
```

yields (won't preserve order):

```
[('15', 1), ('10', 1), ('16', 2)]
```

Using `collections.OrderedDict` and reversing twice allows to preserve order too

```
import collections

result = list(reversed(list(collections.OrderedDict(reversed(list_values)).items())))
```

results in:

```
[('10', 1), ('16', 2), ('15', 1)]
```

That, unless Python 3.6+ is used, where dictionaries retain insertion order. From python 3.5 you can remove some forced list conversions so that will work:

```
list(reversed(collections.OrderedDict(reversed(list_values)).items()))
```

Comment: This is very appealing!

Comment: `OrdredDict` is reversible, no need for one of those `list()` calls. Will also work with regular dict in Py 3.8

Comment: `list(reversed(collections.OrderedDict(reversed(list_values)).items()))` i mean

Comment: yes. Not working for me with the above error. `dict()` and `dict_items()` aren't sequences

Comment: it's new for Py 3.5

Comment: okay. I'm stuck in the past on my machine. I prefer providing solutions that work for most python distros. Added

Answer (score 1):

very bad that the OP not try or not show us some solution, but here the simple one:

```
list_values = [("10",1),("10",2),("16",2),("16",1),("15",1)]
Result = list(dict(reversed(list_values)).items())
print(Result)
```

will give you:

```
[('15', 1), ('16', 2), ('10', 1)]
```

Comment: Can you tell us, why he wants ("16",2) why not ("16",1) and same goes for ("10",1),("10",2).?

Comment: just first founded in the list means unique for his logic.